# Github Action - Check for new PyPI package version

Tags: pypi, github-actions

I want to make a Github action to automatically start a DockerHub build on PyPI package update who depends my program.

For the Dockerhub part, no real problem, just call the webhook.
For the PyPI part is more difficult for me. I don't know how get a package version from Github action. I think to use tag on my repo to store the latest known version of the PyPI package to compare.

If you can help me on how:

- From Github action, I can get PyPI package version
- Compare to a Github repo tag or any other better idea
- Confirm that for call the DockerHub webhook, I need to use https://github.com/marketplace/actions/workflow-webhook-action

Thanks to you

Comment: What have you already tried?

Comment: In Github action, nothing, I don't know how to begin with.
For the PyPI package version, I think I can use https://pypi.org/simple/<packagename>

Comment: Trying now to use : https://github.com/marketplace/actions/compare-binary-against-pypi

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I can't find anything so I decided to make my own Github action to do this.
You can check and use it here : https://github.com/Verbalinsurection/track-pypi-version